# Codesign error - SecKey API returned: -67671

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, codesign

When I try to run codesign of a particular app, I get an error:

`/Users/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx.app: replacing existing signature`

`SecKey API returned: -67671 (null)/Users/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx.app`

`unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff`

Any idea what this means?

Comment: Have you found any answer to this ?

Comment: I tried unlocking my login.keychain and it worked. ```security unlock-keychain ~/Library/login.keychain```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case needed to do the following:

1. in the **Keychain Access** right click on the Private Key (if it is not seen, expand the Certificate by clicking on the little triangle near it)
2. Choose **Get Info**
3. Go to **Access Control** tab, choose "Allow all applications to access this item"
4. Click **Save changes** button, input the username/passwords if prompted

Also note the Certificate/Key could be not only in you **login** keychain, but also in the **System** keychain. Do the same for both if required.