# Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I tried to code sign an iOS application,
These are the steps that i followed

```
    security create-keychain -p password ${KEYCHAIN}
    security set-keychain-settings -u -t 300 ${KEYCHAIN}
    security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain ${KEYCHAIN}
    security import "$1" -k ${KEYCHAIN} -A -P "${PASSPHRASE}" -A >/dev/null
    security unlock-keychain -p password ${KEYCHAIN}

    /usr/bin/codesign -f -s $IDENTITY --keychain $KEYCHAIN --entitlements $ENTITLEMENTS Payload/Test.app
```

This returned me Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff via ssh.

If i directly execute the code sign command in the machine, it's successfully signing.

The issue is only in Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: I had this issue because I pressed "Deny" accidentally when Xcode asked me to allow access to Keychain. This has helped me: [Can't run Xcode project on device due to certificate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881907/cant-run-xcode-project-on-device-due-to-certificate-issues) (restart the machine!).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Had the same problem a while ago, adding

`security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k password ${KEYCHAIN}`

solved it for me.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is the issue ?
and how did this piece of code solved it ?

Comment: From my reseach at the time I figured that the issue is related to keychain permissions, and that's what this command fixes: it tells the system that the keychain in question is suitable for code signing.

Comment: I opened a github issue with fastlane at the time, https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8797 - maybe some of the info over there helps, even if you're not running fastlane.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but none of them helped,
From the local machine it is able to sign properly but via ssh it is throwing me this error

Comment: Thanks man had to set some other thing as well with this
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain ${KEYCHAIN} to
security list-keychains -d user -s ${KEYCHAIN}

Comment: @Gereon I am still facing the same problem via ssh

Comment: For me I was using a temp keychain, i need to do the above but for some reason I also needed to unlock my Default keychain (my login one in this case).  Only need for high Sierra,

Comment: Incase you don't know what ${KEYCHAIN} is, type `security list-keychains` and select one (should be the paths to the login and system keychain files).

Comment: This works for me, but I had to sign from a normal GUI terminal at least once before it would work.

Answer (score 20):

Got the same issue but while archiving directly from Xcode.
Sharing the solution in case it helps.

Sometimes, Keychain seems to end up in a corrupted state. Using MacOS Sierra too.

Symptoms :

Relogin needed to access Accounts after restarting Xcode
[image: Relogin needed to access Accounts after restarting Xcode]

Prompting for password while using Keychain Access for some operations
[image: Prompting for password while using Keychain Access for some operations]

Keychain Access - Error while accessing login keychain via Change Settings for Keychain ...
[image: Keychain Access - Error while accessing login keychain via Change Settings for Keychain ...]

What fixes it for me is locking and unlocking (password required) the involved Keychain, **login** in my case.

Comment: The locking and unlocking keychain access works for me.. I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.1.. The unknown error -1=fffffff is not meaningful Apple : |

Comment: Strange bug. I don't recall unlocking my keychain, but it was unlocked. Locking it and it's fine again.

Comment: This is the best answer that helped me with my problem and saved a lot of time for me. Thank you, Romano.

Comment: A picture is worth thousand words. Working .

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was stucked with this for a while.  locking/unlocking in KeyChain works.  I am using Xcode 9.2, MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 6):

I am going to chip in as well as I had to try a few more things than the ones mentioned here: the problem was that keychain doesn't like SSH sessions. I had to execute these in my session to fix it:

```
security unlock-keychain -p MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k MY_PASS ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security set-keychain-settings ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

I've also removed my current certificates system/account certificates by removing my account from XCode (I use fastlane to do building) but I suspect that this shouldn't have impacted it.

Comment: Funny. This fixed my code signing issue, but it broke my Git client. My Mac is a Jenkins slave and now it can't check out source code from Git. Any clue on why this could happen?

Comment: And also please explain how to reverse this command if you can.

Comment: Well, I guess you changed your keystore credentials (MY_PASS) and git client can't use the keystore/keychain anymore. 

However, I can't explain how to fix that because I've used MacOS just to set up that agent so my experience here is rather... limited.

Comment: Thanks @TadasŠubonis. Note: If it says username or password is incorrect, then try running the commands without -p <password> parameter and then enter the password when prompted.

Answer (score 5):

@madhu I have been trying to fix the same issue and found that Access Control for the key associated with the certificate in question was set to "Confirm before allowing access" which didn't work in Jenkins.  I modified it (thru Keychain Access gui - Get Info, Access Control) to "Allow all applications to access this item" and my build was successful.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Note that a dialog still came up asking for a password, but then you can say "always".

Answer (score 2):

You might have exported some file like p12 from KeyChain, and when OS asked for your root password, and you denied it, then Xcode will code sign error with this info.

If this maybe so, you should repeat the above action, input your password and click allow, and then it will be ok to code sign.

Answer (score 2):

This happens in a headless build because the prompt for key access cannot be shown or responded to.  The solution is to prevent that prompt from showing by granting access to the key in advance.

Open Keychain Access, find the key for your signing certificate (login-> Certificates, then expand the certificate to reveal its key).  Right-click on the key and select: Get Info -> Access Control, and select "Allow all applications to access this item".

Answer (score 0):

I've tried almost all the existing suggestions over the web, none of them helped...

Finally only re-generating the Provisioning Profile (for AdHoc), re-downloading it and placing it to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` overwriting the existing one saved my life.

By the way, AppStore build was successful all this time, so the issue was definitely in the AdHoc profile itself (pretty strange, since it looked nice by all means).

Comment: Were you facing the same problem that i have posted ??

Comment: Yep, exactly the same `error -1=ffffffffffffffff` via ssh with no visible reason (I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6).

Comment: Hey, I went through all this stuff again today and found out the following: 1) *.mobileprovision files in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` dir must NOT have `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute. It is added by default when downloading from Mac through Safari. This is why re-downloading helped me last time, because I tried downloading from Windows and putting on Mac via WinSCP. 2) The `security` command from the answer must be run too. Just last time I did this before Step #1 and it didn't help, and this time running it helped me (because I already did the Step #1 right).

Comment: Btw, presence of this attribute can be checked via `ls -l@` and can be removed with `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file.mobileprovision`

Comment: I have no clue regarding your scenario, but for the problem i posted didn't have any effect with your solution, might be this could be a solution  for something else

Comment: @MadhuAvinash , have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/q/42402434/2518705 ? It should be possible to allow access for codesign only, if you don't want to make it available for all apps.

Comment: mine is a keychain that is created on the fly and deleted as soon as the signing gets completed

Answer (score 0):

Even though we installed the right certs in the keychain and the right Provisioning Profile under ~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles.

We may also see

```
unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
```

For this error, I tried the below steps to fixed the issue:

1. Reboot the machine, unlock keychain using "securify unlock-keychain", lock the keychain again
2. Remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder.
3. Run carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
4. Open the source code syncing down workspace, run "xattr -rc ." then open the .xcodeproject file in xcode.
5. Turned on the automatic signing for each target. Need to login with valid  credentials.
6. Click on the provisioning profile under signing.
7. unlock the keychain again
8. Changing the build device to Generic Devices, under Product --> Clean, then Product –> Archive
9. There will be a keychain access allow showed up, click "Always Allow".
10. You should make sure the archive is successful then trigger the Jenkins job again.