# Jenkins and Xcode 8 automatic code signing

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, code-signing

I am trying to do a basic Jenkins setup. I have a simple Xcode project with  `Automatically manage signing`. I want Jenkins to download the project and build it.

What I did:

1) Installed Jenkins locally on my mac (under `Shared/Jenkins`)
2) Inside Jenkins created a Free style project and configured it to download the project from git
3) Created a separate keychain in `Shared/Jenkins/xcode.keychain-db` and added to it developers and distribution certificates
4) Copied all automatically generated provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` to `Shared/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
5) In Jenkins created a build script

```
security -v unlock-keychain -p myspass ${HOME}/xcode.keychain-db
xcodebuild clean build -target SampleCIApp -configuration Debug DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=…
```

Build fails with:

```
Probing signature of /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '28B8F63A10AC0B5B39826E75B559232121EF686E' '--verbose' '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '28B8F63A10AC0B5B39826E75B559232121EF686E' '--verbose' '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SampleCIApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/SampleCIApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}
```

It looks like something to do with code signing. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173831/codesign-returned-unknown-error-1-ffffffffffffffff)