# Can't run app from Xcode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have app which is running fine on iPhone 7Plus simulator but fails when I try it on real iPhone 7Plus device. Error I get is

```
Debug-iphoneos/MyTDM.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTDM-gokgkswhipemjzaepsulniokxpvp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTDM.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' 'C90533B5B5B3E397F0328467315FAC758CD1EEA3' '--verbose' '/Users/daliborondra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTDM-gokgkswhipemjzaepsulniokxpvp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyTDM.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}
```

Note that my Provisioning Profile seems to look good and I was able to run apps on device in the past without any issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173831/codesign-returned-unknown-error-1-ffffffffffffffff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three hours of frustration I deleted all iOS Developer certificates and started to build app signing from the scratch. Also XCode access to Keeychain to be allowed for all actions = it's important to press such button in the dialog - not only "allow access" but "always allow access".