# Jenkins return "unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff" when building Xcode Project with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm getting below error when trying to build Xcode workspace on Jenkins

> usr/bin/codesign --force --sign B5E96BDFADAF51D771B158A29BF1D16565215A2D  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/servicebuild/Desktop/Jenkins/workspace/Hello-Branch/build/Hello Test.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
>   16:06:07 /Users/servicebuild/Desktop/Jenkins/workspace/Hello-Branch/build/Hello Test.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
>   16:06:07 Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
>   16:06:07 
>   16:06:07 ** BUILD FAILED **
>   16:06:07 
>   16:06:07 
>   16:06:07 The following build commands failed:
>   16:06:07    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/servicebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hello-dcvxwbnovymfusbrvfyyekingznu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Garanti\ Filo.build/Release-iphoneos/Hello\ Hello\ Test.build/Script-2617FEF7DE193736656550249B.sh

I have more than one targets and in workspace scheme targets that I created are ticked as shared (not the pod targets). In pod project every framework has "Don't Code Sign" (As Default). I can successfully get IPA export from Xcode. However, when I try to build in Jenkins I get this error.

I tried solution in below post but can't figure out. I think the problem is Jenkins is forcing to sign pods when It doesn't need to.

[Codesign returned unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173831/codesign-returned-unknown-error-1-ffffffffffffffff)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550594/jenkins-xcode-build-works-codesign-fails) related to what are you facing?

Comment: I have just one certificate and its private key in Jenkins machine so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to run below code (posted in the post added in my question) and it worked. Important point is that giving right path for keychain and password. Otherwise, It doesn't work.

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k password ${KEYCHAIN}
```